# How do I prove this function is injective? $f(x)=e^x+x+1$

Tags: calculus, functions

$f(x)=e^x+x+1$
I know that for a function to be injective it must satisfy the next property:
For any $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb R, f(x_1)=f(x_2) => x_1 = x_2$.
Applying this to my function:
$e^{x_1}+x_1+1=e^{x_2}+x_2+1$
$e^{x_1}+x_1=e^{x_2}+x_2$
I don't know what to do next, I tried grouping terms differently but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Can you show the function is strictly increasing?

Comment: Can you use the fact that your function is continuous and monotonically increasing?

Comment: $f'(x) = e^x+1 \ge 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Yeah, the function is increasing, but I don't see the connection still.

Comment: If $f$ is strictly increasing, then $x_1<x_2$ implies $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$, so, in particular, $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. If $x_1>x_2$, then $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$, so, in particular, $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. So, by contraposition, if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, we must already have $x_1=x_2$. Thus, strictly increasing functions are injective.

Comment: Oh, this is so cool, I had no clue. Thanks a lot, this will be very useful to me!

Comment: Claim:  All increasing monotonic functions are injective.  .... Now that that claim has been stated and now that you have read it, can you see why that claim might be true?  After all if $x < y$ then $f(x) < y$ and we can't have $f(x) = f(y)$.  And if $y < x$ then $f(x) < f(y)$ and we can't have $f(x) = f(y)$.  SO if $f(x) = f(y)$ then *didn't* have either $x < y$ or $x > y$.  So what *did* we have?

Comment: I am not smart enough to write proofs like this, but If I think about the graph of any increasing or decreasing function, it makes perfect sense now that it can't not be injective.

Answer (score 0):

Using
$$ e^t\ge t+1\qquad\text{with equality iff }t=0,$$
we have
$$\begin{align} f(x_1)-f(x_2)&=(e^{x_1}+x_1+1)-(e^{x_2}+x_2+1)\\&=
e^{x_2}(e^{x_1-x_2}-1)+x_1-x_2\\
&\ge e^{x_2}(x_1-x_2)+(x_1-x_2)\\
&=e^{x_1}(x_1-x_2).\end{align}$$
If $x_1>x_2$, this shows $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$.

Comment: how did you get $e^{x_2}(x_1-x_2)+(x_1-x_2)=e^{x_1}(x_1-x_2)$?

Answer (score 0):

we know that $e^x > 0$. And we know that $e^0 = 1$ and $e^x > 1$ if $x > 0$ and $e^x < 1$ if $x < 0$.

So if $x < y$ then $0 < y-x$ and $e^0 = 1 < e^{y-x}$ and $e^x*1 < e^{y-x}*e^x$ so $e^x < e^y$

If $x < y$ the $e^x + x+1 < e^y + x+1 < e^y + y + 1$.

So if we ever have $e^x + x + 1 = e^y + y + 1$ it will be impossible for $x < y$ or for $y < x$.  Hence $e^x + x + 1 = e^y + y + 1 \implies x=y$